# elasticsearch_dsl TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc_type'

Tags: elasticsearch

```
class Article(Document):
    title = Text(analyzer='snowball', fields={'raw': Keyword()})
    body = Text(analyzer='snowball')
    tags = Keyword()
    published_from = Date()
    lines = Integer()

    class Index:
        name = 'blog45'
        settings = {
          "number_of_shards": 2,
        }

    def save(self, ** kwargs):
        self.lines = len(self.body.split())
        return super(Article, self).save(** kwargs)

    def is_published(self):
        return datetime.now() >= self.published_from

# create the mappings in elasticsearch
Article.init()

# create and save and article
article = Article(meta={'id': 42}, title='Hello world!', tags=['test'])
article.body = ''' looong text '''
article.published_from = datetime.now()
article.save() ### BOMBS HERE!!! ###
```

My save() always throws the error:

> TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc_type'

The example above was taken from the documentation but does not work correctly. How can I specify the [doc_type]?

In elasticsearch-py, its

```
res = elastic_client.index(index="bb8_index", body=doc, doc_type='_doc')
```

Comment: Please add full error Trackback here.

Comment: I believe you can either set it in meta where you set id, or you can add `class Meta: doc_type = '_doc'` in your Article class

Comment: @ekmcd I tried adding that as well but it still bombs, I'm pretty sure this library is not compatible with the current Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2/1/2020:

I would avoid using the elasticsearch_dsl library as it isn't able to save/index a document to Elasticsearch. The library is not compatible with the latest Elasticsearch (7.5+).

Use the regular elasticsearch-py library